# How to match the text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, moderncv, text

As in below picture - how to match the text?[image]

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{banking} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstylebanking}{%
\let\oldmakecvtitle\makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  {\centering\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}\par\vspace{10pt}}%
  \oldmakecvtitle%
}%
}{%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage[scale=0.88]{geometry}



\section{Experience}
\cventry{2015--2016}{Data Assistant}{\textsc{Letra S.C.}}{Gdynia}{}{Support in handling all data management activities through the organization effectively
\newline{}
Responsibilities:
\begin{itemize}
\item Provide relevant data to the organization for references as and when instructed
\item Assist the data analyst in making inferences and drawing conclusions
\item Represent the data graphically to ensure the information reaches the reader in simplified manner
\newline{}
\cventry{2015--2016}{Data Assistant}{\textsc{Letra S.C.}}{Gdynia}{}{Support in handling all data management activities through the organization effectively
\newline{}
Responsibilities:
\begin{itemize}
\item Provide relevant data to the organization for references as and when instructed
\item Assist the data analyst in making inferences and drawing conclusions
\item Represent the data graphically to ensure the information reaches the reader in simplified manner
\end{itemize}}
\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "match the text"?

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code compilable, i.e. add the necessary `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` and other commands.

Answer (score 1):

`\cventry`s are not meant to be nested, since the contents is set within fixed-width boxes (either as a `tabular` with a fixed-width column, or a `minipage`). As such, nesting content with different indentations (like a list), will result in misaligned display.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\firstname{John}
\lastname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\section{Experience}

\cventry
  {2015--2016}
  {Data Assistant}
  {\textsc{Letra S.C.}}
  {Gdynia}
  {}
  {Support in handling all data management activities through the organization effectively \newline
    Responsibilities:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Provide relevant data to the organization for references as and when instructed
      \item Assist the data analyst in making inferences and drawing conclusions
      \item Represent the data graphically to ensure the information reaches the reader in simplified manner
    \end{itemize}}

\cventry
  {2015--2016}
  {Data Assistant}
  {\textsc{Letra S.C.}}
  {Gdynia}
  {}
  {Support in handling all data management activities through the organization effectively \newline
    Responsibilities:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Provide relevant data to the organization for references as and when instructed
      \item Assist the data analyst in making inferences and drawing conclusions
      \item Represent the data graphically to ensure the information reaches the reader in simplified manner
    \end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```